# Angularjs - Asynchronous Directive Result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a directive which allows my user select an item over a list of options and, after user performs the selection, it'll return the selected item as result of a promise.

I'm trying to do something like this: [Creating Asynchronous Alerts, Prompts and Confirms in AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2632-creating-asynchronous-alerts-prompts-and-confirms-in-angularjs.htm)

The scenario is: My user will click on a button, for example; It'll bring up the options list over my directive (or something else), creating a promise; User selects an item; The initial promise is resolved with selected item as result:

```
function buttonHandler() {
    MyDirective.showOptions(config).then(function(selectedItem) {
        vm.item = selectedItem;
    })
}
```

Another problem is showing the options list inside a controller, for example.

Is it possible to do with AngularJS directives? Or should I use another approach to reach this result?

Sorry if I'm asking something weird.

**UPDATE:**

After discussing with @Claies about the situation I was trying to solve with this "directive" I realized my question needs more info.

The real scenario is relatad to a product form. It has a bunch of inputs which represents product's brand, type, color, etc. Each one of these inputs has a list of options that comes from different APIs i.e. One for brand, another for type, etc.
In terms of UI, when the user triggers the selection operation, the entire form should be hidden and the options list should take its place. Any input should be able to trigger this "option selection" state and after performing a selection the result should appear into the input which triggered the operation. 
With this in mind, I thought it could be useful handling user selection over a promise and set the product's property when it get resolved.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear about what you are trying to achieve.  You return a promise when you are waiting for a result from something which would normally be a blocking operation (i.e. a server call).  In this case, there doesn't seem to be a reason for the list to be a blocking call, other than the fact that it's waiting on the user. However, the UI itself isn't blocking, so there isn't really a reason that a promise should be necessary.

Comment: I understand the article's take on creating non blocking versions of `alert()`, `prompt()`, and `confirm()`, as they *are* blocking, but an options list isn't blocking.

Comment: Yes you can do those things with directives. Give us a code sample. For more information on directives look at the [AngularJS Directives Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: @Claies I guess my situation is related to a "blocking operation" too, since it'll be a component with some "states". I mean, my user will pass over 3 steps: 
- At the beginning it's a container, with selected item reference and something to "trigger" the selection operation.
- When the user activates the option selection, my component will hide the previous state and show a list of options. (Like a modal, or you choose,  or cancel)
- After the user chooses an option, the options list is released, and our promise will be resolved with the selection, getting back to the initial state.

Comment: @georgeawg I'll try to build a jsfiddle with a sample and I'll post it later. Thank you.

Comment: So your question is really about how to create a blocking modal?  That is the opposite of creating a promise. A promise is for when you want to allow the user to continue while you wait for something else to finish; what you are describing is actually stopping the user.

Comment: @Claies Yes i'm trying to simulate a blocking operation (such a modal) and return the conclusion over a promise. However, you're right, I understand the promise's purpose, and thinking about what I was trying to achieve, it doesn't make sense using a promise. Anyway, It could be useful, isn't? Can you give me any Idea of how I could achieve this result without using a promise?  Thank you at all.

Comment: @Claies In addition, I'll update my initial question with the exact scenario I'm trying solve with this directive.